# config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/endian.h: File or directory not found

Tags: c, ubuntu, compiler-errors, compilation, xen

I would like to pass the integrated gpu from the host os (ubuntu 20.04) to the windows 10 guest os with xen. This is because xen works great for me,better than qemu-kvm for my specific needs and because I have only two graphic cards. The nvidia rtx 2080 ti that I have already passed to the guest,and the intel UHD 630,that can be duplicated from the host to the guest so that it can be used in both places without interruptions. So I'm trying to build this repository :

https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/GVTg_Setup_Guide#332-build-qemu--xen-for-xengt

exploring the log,I see this situation :

```
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/endian.h: File o directory non esistente
    1 | #include <sys/endian.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc6WBNSk.o: in function `main':
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-build/config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2: undefined reference to `sin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEQrVtw.o: in function `main':
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-build/config-temp/qemu-conf.c:4: undefined reference to `timer_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

config-temp/qemu-conf.c: In function ‘main’:
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:25: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
    2 | int main(void) { return sem_timedwait(0, 0); }
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:25: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 2) [-Wnonnull]

config-temp/qemu-conf.c: In function ‘main’:
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:25: error: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Werror=nonnull]
    2 | int main(void) { return sem_timedwait(0, 0); }
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:2:25: error: null argument where non-null required (argument 2) [-Werror=nonnull]
```

It seems that the compilation stops because this :

```
config-temp/qemu-conf.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/endian.h: File o directory non esistente
    1 | #include <sys/endian.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**This is the qemu-conf.c file :**

root@ziomario-z390aoruspro:/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-build/config-temp# nano qemu-conf.c

```
include <semaphore.h>
int main(void) { return sem_timedwait(0, 0); }
```

Someone of you can help me to fix this bug ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`endian.h` is normaly located directly under includes/ in linux.

You've got to have the glibc headers installed and change the source file(s) to `#include <endian.h>` instead.

Comment: the problem was totally different. I fixed this with this patch : https://patchew.org/QEMU/20190617114114.24897-1-berrange@redhat.com/